# Can I use swift sdk in app which runs on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios7, sdk

I'm trying to develop a swift SDK that will work in apps running on iOS 7,
I don't care if my SDK will work only when the app is running on iOS 8 but I don't want to force the target app to run only on iOS.

when I tried to change my Deployment Target to 7.0 and upload the app to appstore I'm getting the following errors:

[image: Upload errors]

> Archive submission failed with errors:
>   ! ERROR 'TMS-90362: "Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key
>   •MinimumOSVersion• in bundle MiniAppDemo.app/Frameworks/ 
>   MiniAppFramework.framework is invalid. The minimum value is 8.0"
>   ERROR IT MS-90362: "Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key
>   'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle
>   MiniAppDemo.app/Frameworks/MiniAppFramework.framework is invalid. The 
>   minimum value is 8.0" 
>   ERROR ITMS-9020g: "Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at
>   'MiniAppDemo.app/Frameworks/MiniAppFramework.frameworW 
>   MiniAppFrameworkl does not have proper segment alignment. Try
>   rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version."  ERROR IT MS-90209:
>   •Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at
>   'MiniAppDemo.app/FrameworksWiniAppFramework.frameworWMiniAppFramework'
>   does not have proper  segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with
>   the latest Xcode version." 
>   ERROR 'TMS-90125: "The binary is invalid.
>   The encryption info in the LC ENCRYPTION INFO load command is either
>   missing or invalid, or the  binary is already encrypted. This binary
>   does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker."  ERROR
>   ITMS-g012S: •The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the load
>   command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already
>   encrypted. This binary  does not seem to have been built with Apple's
>   linker. •  WARNING ITMS-900BO•. "The executable
>   'Payload/MiniAppDemo.app/Frameworks/MiniAppFramework.framework' is not
>   a Position Independent  Executable. Please ensure that your build
>   settings are configured to create PIE executables.  For more
>   information refer to Technical Q&A QA178B -  Building a Position
>   Independent Executable in the iOS Developer Library."  WARNING IT
>   MS-90080: 'The executable
>   'Payload/MiniAppDemo.app/Frameworks/MiniAppFramework.framevvork' is
>   not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your  build
>   settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more
>   information refer to Technical Q&A QAI 788 - Building a Position
>   Independent Executable in the iOS Developer  Done  Library. "

Comment: What is the Xcode version you are using ?

Comment: Your issue is almost similar to https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/352

Comment: @Tushar latest, Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#source-file) for the same issue :

"Embedded frameworks require a minimum deployment target of iOS 8 or OS X Mavericks.

To use Alamofire with a project targeting iOS 7, **you must include all Swift files located inside the Source directory directly in your project.** See the 'Source File' section for additional instructions."

Comment: I can't upgrade the original app to 7.0 (I'm not the owner, I'm developing SDK to add to this app), can I stay in iOS 7 and make it work? I'm using the latest xcode

Comment: The maximum deployment target should be 7.0 to use swift. Also according to above answer you must include all the swift source code of the framework in the app to make it work.